# Replace values ​in one listing with others

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a listing called **'list_connect'**, whose inner lists contain key values ​​from 1 to 21 (for this example). 21 is because it obeys the enumeration of my data that comes from the list called **'list_data'**.

```
list_data = [[ 1, 'Col', 'A', 'B'], 
             [ 2, 'Col', 'E', 'F'], 
             [ 3, 'Col', 'I', 'J'], 
             [ 4, 'Col', 'M', 'N'], 
             [ 5, 'Col', 'B', 'C'], 
             [ 6, 'Col', 'F', 'G'], 
             [ 7, 'Col', 'J', 'K'], 
             [ 8, 'Col', 'N', 'O'], 
             [ 9, 'Col', 'C', 'D'], 
             [10, 'Col', 'G', 'H'], 
             [11, 'Col', 'K', 'L'], 
             [12, 'Col', 'O', 'P'], 
             [13, 'Row', 'B', 'F'], 
             [14, 'Row', 'F', 'J'], 
             [15, 'Row', 'J', 'N'], 
             [16, 'Row', 'C', 'G'], 
             [17, 'Row', 'G', 'K'], 
             [18, 'Row', 'K', 'O'], 
             [19, 'Row', 'D', 'H'], 
             [20, 'Row', 'H', 'L'], 
             [21, 'Row', 'L', 'P']]

list_connect = [[1, 5, 13], [2, 6, 13, 14], [3, 7, 14, 15], [4, 8, 15], [1, 5, 9, 13, 16], 
                [2, 6, 10, 13, 14, 16, 17], [3, 7, 11, 14, 15, 17, 18], [4, 8, 12, 15, 18], 
                [5, 9, 16, 19], [6, 10, 16, 17, 19, 20], [7, 11, 17, 18, 20, 21], [8, 12, 18, 21]]

lx = [7, 5, 4, 6, 7, 5, 4, 6, 7, 5, 4, 6, 7, 3, 5, 7, 5, 3, 5, 5, 1]

ly = [1, 9, 4, 1, 1, 9, 4, 1, 1, 9, 4, 1, 5, 1, 1, 6, 1, 3, 2, 1, 4]

list_final = []
for i in range(len(list_data)):
    for j in range(len(list_connect)):
        if list_data[i][1] == 'Col':
            lx in list_connect
        else:
            ly in list_connect
```

In addition to this I have two lists **'lx'** and **'ly'**, whose length is equal to the length of **'list_data'** (21 in both cases).

What I'm looking for is to replace the key values ​​of my listing **'list_connect'** with the values ​​of **'lx'** and **'ly'** in the positions given by **'list_connect'**.
The logic is:
If list_data [i] [1] == 'Col', take values ​​from list **'lx'** and replace, else take the other list **'ly'** and replace.

To illustrate the objective I have the following list 'list_connect'

```
[[1, 5, 13], [2, 6, 13, 14], [3, 7, 14, 15], [4, 8, 15], [1, 5, 9, 13, 16], [ 2, 6, 10, 13, 14, 16, 17], [3, 7, 11, 14, 15, 17, 18], [4, 8, 12, 15, 18], [5, 9, 16, 19], [6, 10, 16, 17, 19, 20], [7, 11, 17, 18, 20, 21], [8, 12, 18, 21]]
```

After this, I should have this new list 'list_final':

```
[[75, 71, 54], [56, 58, 54, 19], [47, 40, 19, 18], [66, 63, 18], [75, 71, 77, 54, 66], [ 56, 58, 59, 54, 19, 66, 17], [47, 40, 41, 19, 18, 17, 3], [66, 63, 61, 18, 3], [71, 77, 66, 223], [58, 59, 66, 17, 223, 119], [40, 41, 17, 3, 119, 46], [63, 61, 3, 46]]
```

Comment: How do you get `[75, 71, 54]` from the data in your question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you *describe* in your question can be implemented with a nested list comprehension:

```
list_final = [
              [lx[v-1] if list_data[v-1][1] == 'Col' else ly[v-1] for v in c] 
              for c in list_connect
              ]
```

This gives an output (for your sample data) of:

```
[
 [7, 7, 5],
 [5, 5, 5, 1],
 [4, 4, 1, 1],
 [6, 6, 1],
 [7, 7, 7, 5, 6],
 [5, 5, 5, 5, 1, 6, 1],
 [4, 4, 4, 1, 1, 1, 3],
 [6, 6, 6, 1, 3],
 [7, 7, 6, 2],
 [5, 5, 6, 1, 2, 1],
 [4, 4, 1, 3, 1, 4],
 [6, 6, 3, 4]
]
```